# When do asserts become redundant?

Tags: c++, assert

I'm writing some collision detection code for a small project, and I have this for rectangular collisions:

```
bool RectColl(const SDL_Rect *r1, const SDL_Rect *r2)
{
    assert(r1 != nullptr);
    assert(r2 != nullptr);
    // cool stuff here
}
```

and this for pixel-perfect collisions

```
bool PPColl(const SDL_Rect *r1, const SDL_Surface *s1, const SDL_Rect *r2, const SDL_Surface *s2)
{
    assert(r1 != nullptr);
    assert(r2 != nullptr);
    assert(s1 != nullptr);
    assert(s2 != nullptr);

    // Make sure that it's got rectangular collision
    if(!RectColl(r1, r2))
        return false;
    // more cool collision detection code here
}
```

As you can see, I'm doing an assert for r1 and r2 twice when I call PPColl. Is this redundant, or should I keep the asserts for the r1 and r2?

Comment: You are going to find many different philosophies on this. But in this  case, you probably want to change the interface to take `const SDL_Rect &` etc. instead. Assertions are good; interfaces that are impossible to use wrong are better.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of that. I'll keep that idea in mind for the future.

Comment: They are truly redundant when you have taken measures to ensure they are never false, such as switching to references, use of static_assert or using an attribute that ensures the argument is not null (see gcc/clangs nonnull attribute). But assert terminates your program so they should be annotation of what your code expects to never happen anyway.

Comment: All asserts are redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Asserts are *supposed* to be redundant, in that they should be checking things that your code ensures are always true anyway. Their purpose is to catch things that are you *think* are always true but are in fact false by mistake. The sort of problem they catch is often as a result of *future* changes to the code rather than the current state of the program.

In this case your asserts serve different purposes, and should all be kept. The ones in `PPColl` are checking that *it* is never called with null arguments. The ones in `RectColl` have nothing to do with `PPColl`'s arguments; they are checking `RectColl`'s arguments. If `RectColl` is only ever called by `PPColl` then these are the same thing and so they have already been checked, but that's a property of the code *now*; if you removed `RectColl`'s asserts you could fail to catch a future bug where some other code calls it as well with arguments that might be null, or if `PPColl` is later changed to be able to accept null pointers to mean something, or any of a number of other possible changes.

Comment: Assert will be discarded in Release mode anyway.